# Build Failed while using SwiftShield?

Tags: ios, swift, obfuscation

I used this command to obfuscate my project.

```
swiftShield -automatic -project-root .../ObfuscatingProject -automatic-project-file .../ObfuscatingProject/ObfuscatingProject.xcodeproj -automatic-project-scheme ObfuscatingProject
```

Response says this,

```
The following build commands failed:
    Ld .../Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ObfuscatingProject-dbsfnftojfasjxfbiayltcmwtvvw/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ObfuscatingProject.app/ObfuscatingProject normal arm64
(1 failure)
```

Why I am having this error and how to fix it?

Comment: @12478475 is that issue resolved?

Comment: Is this issue resolved?